# Making connections sturdy

Tags: pcb, wiring, breadboard

TL;DR:

- How should I connect the LED strip 3 wire JST connectors to the breadboard so they are less likely to fall out

  Found the answer I think: [Terminal Blocks](https://www.google.com/search?q=terminal+blocks&tbm=isch)
- How should I connect the LED strip 3 wire JST connectors to a final product (no breadboard) in a way they are sturdy (not likely to break off) (directly to the Teensy?
  To another board? Via some other type of connector?

  I think this is the same as above, [terminal Blocks](https://www.google.com/search?q=terminal+blocks&tbm=isch)
  on a circuit board
- How should I connect the LED power and capacitors to the power connectors so they are sturdy and unlikely to disconnect/break off/fall out

  Still need some suggestions here
- How should I connect the resistors on the data lines, between the LED strip 3 wire JST connectors and the Teensy, in a way they are unlikely to break? Via a custom board? Some other wrapper?

  I think the answer here is put the resistors in a circuit board though looking at the breadboard if I use a breadboard shaped PCB I'm not sure how to run the resistors so far over except with lots of shrink tubing or else etch a custom board. Are there other solutions?

---

Details:

I'm wondering what I should do to make my circuits physically sturdy so that wires are unlikely to bend a bunch and come off or come undone.

Maybe "sturdy" is the wrong word because I've been searching for "sturdy electronics" and not had much luck. "robust electronics" isn't any better but I think robust suggests not going to break if too much power (like adding a fuse) which is not what I'm asking about.

Some examples. I have these tiny resistors with tiny tiny wires.

[image]

I'm suppose to put one on each data line for an LED strip project. I managed to put one on, cutting the lead down to probably 1/4" and soldering them on but when I'm done I have no confidence they'll hold and those tiny wires on the resistor won't snap. What should I do going forward. Is this a place where I should put the resistors on some custom circuit board?

As another example, the first time I used a Teensy 4.0 I just soldered the LED strip 3 wire JST connectors straight to it.

[image]

Originally I had just one connector. Every time I'd unplug/plug the USB power or unplug/plug the USB to the computer the odds of the teensy turning 90 degrees in my fingers and be pressing all the wires down was about 1 out of 3 times. Eventually 2 wires busted off. What should I have done?

Continuing with that same project but another fresh Teensy 4.0 I tried to use a breadboard. I soldered on the headers upside down since I needed to wire things to the back of the board

[image]

But even here the LED strip 3 wire JST connectors, the ends of which look like this

[image]

Don't fit securely into the breadboard. I striped about 1/8" more off the ends of wires and managed to get them in but the slightest brush and they come out.

[image]

What should I have done here so they were more strongly attached to the breadboard? Should I have soldered on some breadboard leads?

[image]

I didn't do that since I'd have to remove them when I stop using the breadboard. Maybe I should have used alligator breadboard leads?

[image]

Even the power connectors, I used the ones seen below but with a capacitor + the LED strip power wire in the connector but often I guess the capacitor wire is holding the connector wire clamp too wide so the LED strip power wire slides out easily.

[image]

I suppose I should solder the LED strip power wires to the capacitor leads and then stick the capacitor leads into the power connectors? What should I do when I actually want to take this thing out of the lab (my desk) and into the real world (a costume). In words, how should I cover/brace/surround these capacitors and wire connections so they're sturdy? I can add some shrink tube to each lead and then a big one over the whole thing I guess like this

[image]

The white shrink tube was not actually big enough to go over the power connector. Maybe I should just goop hot glue all over it? Is there a recommended way to do this?

Similarly while I have the LED strip 3 wire JST connectors in the breadboard (poorly, see above) when I actually want to go to my costume how should I attach them to the Teensy? Is the normal thing a custom circuit board? Even then with a custom board they'd stick out just like 2nd picture above just from a bigger board so I'd still need to do something else to prevent them from breaking off easily.

I hope this is an appropriate question here since it's kind of indirectly about electronics. Maybe this is such common knowledge that I just searched for the wrong words in trying to find solutions.

Comment: Breadboard ≠ Sturdy. Focus on your problem and try and get to the crux of what your problem is.

Comment: Strain relief is what you use to make things 'sturdy'

Answer (score 2):

Search "breadboard neatly or neat

- AWG22-24 gauge insulated hookup wire can be breadboarded neatly to lay flat on the board. - axial resistors, bent carefully and trimmed to look radial with 5mm leads
- square pin headers fit into breadboards but can stretch the contacts, so use a socket

https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=neat+breadboard&ia=images&iax=images

- solid wire jumpers can be reused and kept in a jar or make some. https://www.instructables.com/id/Make-your-own-U-Shaped-Breadboard-Wires/
- But 1/4W plated steel resistor wire is sturdy and fits well into breadboard sockets if kept short.
- You can use the cut wires for short jumpers if preshaped well.
- strain relief for wires is another search word.
- alligator clips have short lives as the stranded wires break after a few dozen uses or less

Clean, rugged, mechanical-interfacing may be the hardest to learn as they do not teach this in EE school.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Strain relief lead to some solutions. I'm not sure how the solid wire jumpers help. You can see in the 3rd image above I have 4 solid wire jumps in the image. What I don't have is a way to connect the LED cables to the breadboard in any reasonably secure way. Of course I'm not expecting the breadboard to be anything other than temporary but as it is now moving the board at all will knock out the LED cables they are so loose. Any ideas what I should do there next time?

Comment: Okay, I guess I found ["terminal blocks"](https://www.google.com/search?q=terminal+blocks&tbm=isch) which I can use for that next time.

Comment: It depends how many signals you need to “interconnect” on a breadboard. E.g. a thruhole CAT5 connector or a ribbon wire with the socket used as a receptacle for remote wiring or LED sockets...

Comment: In my case I'm specifically trying to connect LED strip 3 wire JST connectors (shown above) so I just want to check, it sounds like you're suggesting I solder those to a CAT5 cable as one solution and then put a CAT5 socket on the breadboard. Or solder those to a ribbon cable and put a ribbon cable socket on the breadboard. Not sure how the LED sockets would help with LED strip 3 wire JST connectors but just checking I understand your suggestion.

Comment: something like that.  or a long header can be cut to length but more unused pins increases retention force. Round pins shouldn't damage sockets like square post headers might.  https://www.goldmine-elec-products.com/products.asp?dept=1056 or solder to a right angle header with enough pins for ruggedness.